# How to activate the Speed Graph of the Graph Editor of Adobe Aftereffects 2022?

Tags: after-effects, adobe

How to activate the Speed Graph of the Graph Editor of Adobe Aftereffects 2022?

In the tutorial that I'm watching now, when he pressed his Graph editor, the result looked like the one that is encircled.

[image: GraphEditorofAftereffects]

But when I pressed my Graph Editor in my Adobe Aftereffects 2022, the result look quite different from his, like this:

[image: TooDifferentGraphEditor]

I don't understand why the same icon produces different functions for him and for me. How do we activate the Speed Graph of the Adobe Aftereffects 2022?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used Orientation, and he has used Rotation. He has also separated the dimensions, which means that for a 3D object, you will see three separate graphs for x, y, and z rotations. Then he's selected only the Y rotation keyframes.